# System tray icon not active when app started at Windows start-up

Tags: java, windows, system-tray

I have written an app which register an icon to the system tray. When I launch it directly, my icon is visible and perfectly functional but, when I try to have my app automatically started when Windows starts, the app doesn't appear...

In the system tray personalization window, my app is correctly listed, but when I select "display icon and notifications" for it, Windows tells me this icon is not active and will be only visible when it get's active.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In certain situations your application might be running before the taskbar is ready. The workaround for this is to [listen for the TaskbarCreated registered message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/taskbar#taskbar-creation-notification) and add your icon again.

Comment: But how do I do this in Java?

Comment: If there is no native support for the `RegisterWindowMessage` function you have to use JNI or something along those lines